# How to repair stripped, leaky pneumatic fitting?

Tags: aluminum, threads, pneumatic

I have a pneumatic cylinder with a stripped fitting, which causes a slow leak. I took it to a machine shop and he tried to re-thread it but there wasn't enough good metal left to get a good thread. He told me there wasn't enough room for an oversize fitting and suggested I try liquid thread sealant.

Unfortunately, this hasn't worked. There is still a slow leak.

This is for a DIY RV loft type bed that uses 4 pneumatic cylinders to lift the bed up toward the ceiling, which will never need to support more than about 25 LBS or so - just the weight of the bed.

I'm thinking I should maybe try Blue Block or epoxy, but hoping to get some advice first.

Much thanks...Jon

Comment: Weld another boss on it - but would that still meet safety regs? Get another cylinder and don’t overtighten that one...

Comment: Hey thanks - yeah that's probably good advice. No safety regs involved here. It was a used cylinder. I didn't strip it in the first place :).

Comment: @JonVote, the standard "cheap bast*rd" fix in such a case is silicone RTV caulk. it fills gaps and holds pressure well. glob up the threads with this and screw the fitments together!

Comment: You could JBWeld it together if it never needs to come apart again.  But cutting it off and adding a new one would be the standard solution.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. @niels nielsen - just got your comment on the other thread! I'm in Oregon as well. Thanks for what you are doing!

Comment: Just a followup - I followed the suggestion from @Tiger Guy and this has worked --- at least so far. Again - this is a non-critical application. Nothing bad will happen if the fix fails. Thanks to all who answered.